# como buscar entre fechas con consultas sql

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

23 Muestra los datos de los alumnos cuya fecha de nacimiento comprenda los
años 1993 y 1994. Ordena el resultado por nombre.

NO FUNCIONA EN PHP MY ADMIN, HAY ALGUNA FORMA DE QUE ESTO FUNCIONE? Y ALGUNO CONOCE DONDE BUSCAR ESTAS COSAS DE PHPMYADMIN?

```
SELECT * FROM fecha_nacimiento BETWEEN '1993-01-12' AND '1994-12-31' ORDER BY nombre;
```

Comment: Que errores te da? Que otra cosa has probado? seguro que tu tabla se llama así?

Comment: Por favor evita el uso de mayúsculas sostenidas. Te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas las normas de la comunidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esa es tu sentencia?

```
SELECT * FROM fecha_nacimiento BETWEEN '1993-01-12' AND '1994-12-31' ORDER BY nombre;
```

Porque no veo ningun tipo de WHERE, PHPMyAdmin usa MySQL como gestor de BD, lo correcto seria

```
SELECT * FROM TuTabla WHERE TuFecha BETWEEN '1993-01-01' AND '1994-12-31'
```

O tambien puede usar un >= y <=

Comment: muchas gracias Mauricio, se me escapó jeje.